# When unit testing (with Mockito), should I "implement" the internal logic when mocking?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Edit:
Sorry, my example is not very proper, I changed it a little.

I'm not sure if the title shows my question properly.
For example, I have functions:

```
class Dependency {
    // create an element with id and data, add it into a list and return the element
    public Element addElement(int id, data d) throws SomeException;

    // remove an element from the list and return it
    public Element removeElement(int id) throws SomeException;
}
```

Then I can mock it like:

```
private Element mockElement(int id, data dt) {
    Element e = mock(Element.class);
    when(e.getId()).thenReturn(id);
    when(e.getData()).thenReturn(dt);
    return e;
}

private Dependency mockDependency() {
    List l = new List();
    Dependency dependency = mock(Dependency.class);    

    // should I "implement" the internal logic when mocking?
    when(dependency.addElement(intCaptor.capture(), dataCapture.capture())).thenAnswer(a->{
        int id = intCaptor.getValue();
        data dt = dataCaptor.getValue();
        if (id < 0) { throw someException; }
        Element e = mockElement(id, dt);
        l.add(e);
        return e;
    };

    when(dependency.removeElement(intCaptor.capture())).thenAnswer(a->{
        int id = intCaptor.getValue();
        if (id < 0) { throw someException; }
        Element e = l.findElementInListById(id);
        if (e == null) { return null; }
        l.remove(e);
        return e;
    };
    return dependency;
}

...

@Test
public void test() {
    ...
    Dependency dependencyMock = mockDependency();
    MyClass c = new MyClass(dependencyMock);

    // it calls dependency.addElement()
    c.addElement(1, data)

    // it calls dependency.removeElement()
    assertEquals(1, c.removeElement(1).getId());
    ...
}
```

This does work, but I wonder if it is a good idea to do so. All the examples I can find online about Mockito are basically simple when().then() statements. Can anyone please give me some advice?

Comment: ..and if  `add/remove`  are system boundaries (e.g. WS calls), you should test your code, and mock (add/remove) where it is used (usually using "thenReturn" or "thenThrow" according to your test case)

Comment: Thanks, guys. I notice that the example is not very good. I changed it a little, do you mind to see it again?

Comment: so, "easy" answered: when add/removeElement is an "external code/call", which testing is too complex/should be considered as black box, (and it works,) then you hit it! ..if add/remove is "own code" (which is used/not too complex/should be tested), then you shouldn't mock (but use the real impl.)

Comment: Thanks @xerx593!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of mocking is to test the functionality you have written, the mocks should be only given for the services that are used by the method being tested.

For example, when you test the method `public Element addElement(int id, data d) throws SomeException;` you should call the original implementation and then you should assert the response that you expect to get for the given input.

Suppose inside `addElement` method you are internally calling a  service `myService.processData` then you should mock the call to the `myService.processData` only and the rest of the flow should be as it would have been had the method been called in real scenario.

You should read more on Unit tests, one link I found is [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/7-tips-writing-unit-tests-java)

EDIT

In the example you have given, I think what you have done is, you have put the code inside the original `dependency.addElement` method inside the mock object you are creating, if you do that you will have to change your test case every time you make a change in the code because once you make a code change in original method `dependency.addElement` the code in test class becomes out of sync with it and you no longer be testing the feature. Even with this code you are not actually testing the original feature since `dependency.addElement` is mocked.

The correct approach is to call the original method `dependency.addElement` with a known input and assert the answer.

I hope this explains it.

Comment: I notice that the example is not very good. I changed it a little, do you mind to see it again?

Comment: updated my answer. hopefully its clear?  Please read the complete answer again. hopefully it will be clear then